# How do I add custom transition in silverlight navigation frame?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have few user controls in a silverlight application and a navigation frame. 
Current User control --> Current source of the frame
Next User Control --> User control that is shown when clicked on a hyper link

When clicked on a hyperlink, I want to add custom transition such that the current page fades, reduces its size and then disappears while fading.  Then I want the reverse to happen on the next user control i.e. the user control that is going to be loaded will appear small, faded out and then expand whilst fading in. Other than using the inbuilt transitions that are provided with transitioncontent control, is there a way to add a storyboard transition to the current control and reverse the transition on the control that the frame is being navigated to?

Answer (score 0):

If you modify the template of the TransitioningContentControl,  you can alter the defined states to change the transition animation to your desired fade and shrink animation.

(I've retemplated TransitioningContentControl in a navigation application for my website,  [www.mikeherman.net](http://mikeherman.net/blog/hello-orchard) )